# 2012 Visual Studio Custom Control Xaml/Style Designer - How to edit generic xaml styles?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, wpf-controls, custom-controls, visual-studio-designer

I have been digging around online and in stack overflow, but maybe I am not asking the question correctly.

I am attempting edit my generic/default custom usercontrol style without opening up Blend.  I want to know how I can edit a default style for a custom user control within VS2012.  It wont let you "Edit Current", and I cant find an equivalent window in VS2012 like blend had where you can see all your resources and styles listed.

Anyone know where this is located at?  The new Xaml editor stuff in VS2012 is fantastic, but custom user controls and their default styles are really important too.

Running VS2012 Ultimate - Update 2

Thanks!

[image: Edit Current unavailable]

[image: cannot be edited in design view]

Comment: user controls and custom controls are different, which are you using?

Comment: Except modifying the xaml by hand, there is no way to edit a template in visual studio.

Comment: Custom Control.. sorry ---   An no way to edit in VS, that sucks.  Its just xaml styles, I don't see why that couldn't be built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in VS directly (this is why Blend exists, i think :), but you can try using [XamlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) to get xaml code of the control you want to modify.

Just create a new WPF application, add a control you want to modify and a button with click handler.

Write the following inside the button click handler:

```
private void OnGetXamlButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string xaml = XamlWriter.Save(MyControl.Style);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I am actually looking to edit it using the WYSIWYG direct in VS instead of opening Blend.  The XamlWriter I don't see how its related.   I am writing controls with default styles.  I am using 2013 now with the update, and I don't believe this is available yet.    I don't like having to open blend just for one simple thing that VS can do for every other xaml file.  Anyhow, thanks for trying to help.